# Does the C++ standard require operator != must be provided for a given iterator type?

Tags: c++, iterator, standards, semantics, type-traits

The C++17 standard `27.2.1.8` says:

> An iterator j is called reachable from an iterator i if and only if
>   there is a finite sequence of applications of the expression ++i that
>   makes i == j.

That is to say, any conforming iterator type must provide `operator ==`.

However, I find nothing about `operator !=` is a requirement for iterator types.

**Does the C++ standard require `operator !=` must be provided for a given iterator type?**

Comment: "*That is to say, any conforming iterator type must provide operator ==.*" That's not where the requirement for `operator==` is spelled out. [Requirements tend to be in tables.](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/input.iterators)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See C++17 [input.iterators]/2 Table 95 "Input iterator requirements".

Input iterators require that `a != b` is valid and behaves the same as `!(a == b)` if the latter is valid.  [Link to cppreference.com summary](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/InputIterator)

Output iterators do not need to support either operation.

Comment: It looks like it's table 95 in n4659, which is supposed to be the same as the C++17 standard except minor editorial changes. Is that a typo, or did "minor editorial changes" really change the numbering by 19 places? Also, here's a [link to the relevant part of an HTML version of n4659](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/input.iterators#2).

Comment: @DanielH thanks, I'd accidentally loaded up a later draft